# NameError During Migrations for Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make migrations but am getting a NameError: name 'Product' is not defined and am not really sure why. I assume it may be something simple but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. The error is happening on line 13(class Orders... is line 12 for quick reference). My models are as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

from phone_field import PhoneField

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = PhoneField(help_text='Contact Phone Number')

class Orders(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    quantity_ordered = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    style = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.OneToOneField(Artist, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    comment = models.TextField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: Place the Product model before the Order model, that should work

Comment: Ahh wow this was so stupid of me to overlook, this was the issue haha. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sumithran the issue was simple, I needed to just place the model in the correct order before referencing them!